# Jenkins list user ids using script console

Tags: scripts, users, jenkins

I want to list all users in jenkins, via the console script that jenkins has.

So far I managed to list all the users using this:

```
import hudson.model.User   
User.getAll().each { user ->   
   println user}
```

but they are listed by the first and last name, which I don't need...

I would like to list them by their user IDs, can you give me a hand?

I looked through the documentation but I fail to understand how to use it the right way.  I'm not so experimented with groovy scripting..

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

According to the [`hudson.modle.User` documentation](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html), you can use the `getId()` method to get the user's id.

Probably like that:

```
import hudson.model.User
User.getAll().each { user ->
println user.getId()}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, sorry for posting this on ask ubuntu instead of serverfault.

I found the perfect way:

```
import hudson.model.User   
import jenkins.model.Jenkins   
def realm = Jenkins.getInstance().getSecurityRealm()   
def users = realm.getAllUsers()   
for (User u : users) {   
    def userid = u.getId()   
    println(userid + " ")   
}
```